# Cpp/Gdb return 0; causing all user's sessions logut

Tags: c++, debugging

I've written C++ application that is causing all *KDE* sessions to logout on program exit. It's clearly impossible behavior, because My application is running around network. I'm not using any *Qt/KDE* libraries that's why I'm surprised. Application causes all sessions to logout on `return 0;` even running under *gdb*. I checked `rip` register before `return 0;` execution. It's pointing to the middle of the `main()` where I got 4 lines of code.

My questions are:

1. Had someone such behavior? I mean sessions logout on `return 0;` at the end of main().
2. Where I should start to investigate My code, what common places are for this kind of errors?
3. How do I save output of *strace*? I tried `$ strace app > strace1`. File was created, but without content (probably caused by session logout).

Whole code is too complex to present it here. I'm working on:

```
 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT1: When running application from tty it logout current user and do DoS, only machine reboot can help. I'll run this on virtual machine, maybe there will be other behavior.

Comment: It would hep if you created a proof of concept app that is smaller than your actual app, but still replicates the problem.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was caused by badly coded logic of application. When I did `return 0;` the destructors of few classes were invoked, one of them was killing child processes.

```
// Proof of concept:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{ kill(-1, SIGKILL); }
```

Just read in *man* that -1 argument kills all processes, except 1. That's cryptic lol.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I save output of strace? I tried `$ strace app > strace1`.

`$ strace app >& strace1` to also redirect STDERR.